# Unexpected behaviour with mutate_each in dplyr - variabel used in mutation got mutated

Tags: r, dplyr

I have encountered unexpected behaviour in dplyr. I was trying to weight all the variables in a dataset by the value of one of the variables. This was dietary data, with nutrition values given per serving. The weight of the serving was known, and I wished to analyse values per gram of food, not per serving.

The serving weight was the tenth numeric variable in the data set. The first nine were converted correctly. The weight variable was set, also correctly, to 1. Subsequent variables were left unaltered (or possibly divided by 1). This was not expected!

The problem could be fixed by creating a new variable at the end of the data frame, holding the value of the serving weight variable. It could also be fixed by leaving the weight variable out of the mutate statement, but I chose not to do this, as it provides a useful check.

Here is a short example that makes my point :-

```
library(dplyr)
a <- letters[1:6]
x1 <- rep(1,6);x2 <- rep(2,6);x3 <- rep(3,6)
x4 <- rep(4,6);x5 <- rep(5,6);x6 <- rep(6,6)
#I want to divide each variable by one of the variables - Two examples
d <- data.frame(a,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)
d %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./x3),x1:x6) #Unexpected!
d %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./x4),x1:x6) #Unexpected!
```

Output:

```
  a        x1        x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1 a 0.3333333 0.6666667  1  4  5  6
2 b 0.3333333 0.6666667  1  4  5  6
3 c 0.3333333 0.6666667  1  4  5  6
4 d 0.3333333 0.6666667  1  4  5  6
5 e 0.3333333 0.6666667  1  4  5  6
6 f 0.3333333 0.6666667  1  4  5  6

     a   x1  x2   x3 x4 x5 x6
1 a 0.25 0.5 0.75  1  5  6
2 b 0.25 0.5 0.75  1  5  6
3 c 0.25 0.5 0.75  1  5  6
4 d 0.25 0.5 0.75  1  5  6
5 e 0.25 0.5 0.75  1  5  6
6 f 0.25 0.5 0.75  1  5  6
```

> Workaround:

```
#Make a new variable at the end of the data frame
d$Three <- d$x3
d$Four <- d$x4

d %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./Three),x1:x6) #Expected!
d %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./Four),x1:x6) #Expected!
```

Output:

```
  a        x1        x2 x3       x4       x5 x6 Three Four
1 a 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2     3    4
2 b 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2     3    4
3 c 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2     3    4
4 d 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2     3    4
5 e 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2     3    4
6 f 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2     3    4

  a   x1  x2   x3 x4   x5  x6 Three Four
1 a 0.25 0.5 0.75  1 1.25 1.5     3    4
2 b 0.25 0.5 0.75  1 1.25 1.5     3    4
3 c 0.25 0.5 0.75  1 1.25 1.5     3    4
4 d 0.25 0.5 0.75  1 1.25 1.5     3    4
5 e 0.25 0.5 0.75  1 1.25 1.5     3    4
6 f 0.25 0.5 0.75  1 1.25 1.5     3    4
```

This does make sense, given that dplyr allows you to create and use new variables as you go along. However, to me this specific behaviour was  counter-intuitive, perhaps because I always think of mutations as atomic. In this case they aren't!

I think I may now have answered my original question, but I will post here for others bitten by the same behaviour. Does this make sense? Have I understood the behaviour correctly?

Comment: I agree that it's not great to always have x1:x6 modified in sequence. It would be nice if that could be turned off.

Comment: Given that you have answered your own question, you might post it as an answer. Then others will see at a glance that the question has been resolved.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Maybe you should report it: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues. Note that you could avoid this behavior without creating a new column by excluding the weighting variable explicitly, eg. `d %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./x3),x1:x6,-x3)`

Comment: scoa is right of course - I only noticed this because there were about 80 columns in my data, and I just used (in effect) v1:v80 everywhere!

Comment: @astaines: (late edit) what Sam Firke actually meant was that that if you found the answer yourself, [you are encouraged to submit it as such](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Adding "answered" to the title is unnecessary, as the "Accepted" mark is enough indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround is to reference the variable preceded by the data frame `d$x3`. Because by default it is applied to all non-grouping variables we just exclude the column `-a` to avoid dividing a factor by a number and generating NAs:

```
d %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./d$x3), -a)
```

Output:

```
  a        x1        x2 x3       x4       x5 x6
1 a 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2
2 b 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2
3 c 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2
4 d 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2
5 e 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2
6 f 0.3333333 0.6666667  1 1.333333 1.666667  2
```

If we were to group, then we would need to use the approach indicated by scoa, excluding that variable, because `d$x3` would produce an error. Note that because we are grouping by the variable `a` we do not need to exclude it this time.

```
d %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate_each(funs(Weight = ./x3), -x3)
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
Groups: a [6]

       a        x1        x2    x3       x4       x5    x6
  (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl) (dbl)    (dbl)    (dbl) (dbl)
1      a 0.3333333 0.6666667     3 1.333333 1.666667     2
2      b 0.3333333 0.6666667     3 1.333333 1.666667     2
3      c 0.3333333 0.6666667     3 1.333333 1.666667     2
4      d 0.3333333 0.6666667     3 1.333333 1.666667     2
5      e 0.3333333 0.6666667     3 1.333333 1.666667     2
6      f 0.3333333 0.6666667     3 1.333333 1.666667     2
```